# Trying to plot a set of forecasted values to the end of my actual values in excel but can't get the dates to line up

Tags: excel, graph, charts, excel-charts

I have a simple line chart in excel. The first series has values that were given from 1/2016 monthly all the way up until 12/1/2019. I was asked to predict the next 12 months and then plot those new predictions on the same chart as the given values.

This is what my chart looks like. I've started with all the dates as the X and the given values up until the end of 2019 as 1 series and then I just tried to add the second series which is just the dates and values for 2020 but for whatever reason, excel things those are happening at the start of 2016. Or maybe it's just using 2 different x axis?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit: Tables
**[image: strong text]**

[image]

Comment: What year is it where you are then? Your predictions on 2020 will probably be wrong, there was a little thing that happened...

Comment: We will need to see the table you have also. Most likely that is where the issue is. Your predicted values should start on the row below your last real value, not on row 2.

Comment: What do you mean something is wrong with the predictions? I've added both my tables. I guess i must be doing it totally wrong b/c I'm adding them as 2 separate series. If I just include the predicted values in the same series, how do I get the chart to differentiate between actual and predicted

Comment: First off, is the dates date cells? If yes then look at the settings of the x-axis, somewhere there is a setting where you can make it use dates, can't remember the setting. I'm typing on my phone so I can't help much more than that.

Comment: Your doing it correctly. You need to make it two series

Comment: yes, they're dates. I just tried messing around with it and I think i got it. If I just add empty values for all the dates from 2016-2019 before I get to the 2020 predictions it seems to work. I'm not really sure why

Comment: That is also a way to make it. Except there is a line now from 0 -> 191 I assume? If you don't tell Excel to read dates as dates in the x-axis then you get this issue that each value is just a value and the x-axis is just text. But if you make the chart understand that it is dates then you shouldn't need the empty values. But good job.